# HttpWebRequest Issue to remote server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-1.1, asp.net-1.1

I'm trying to upload files to a remote server (windows server 2008 R2) from my asp.net 1.1 (C#) Windows application (I know.. It's really old, sadly, that's what we have). When I try to upload, it's giving me an error: "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.". 
Here's the code I'm using:
Any ideas?

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uploadUrl);
req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(uName,pwd);
req.Method = "PUT";
req.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;

// Retrieve request stream 
Stream reqStream = req.GetRequestStream();

// Open the local file
FileStream rdr = new FileStream(txt_filename.Text, FileMode.Open);

// Allocate byte buffer to hold file contents
byte[] inData = new byte[4096];

// loop through the local file reading each data block
//  and writing to the request stream buffer
int bytesRead = rdr.Read(inData, 0, inData.Length);
while (bytesRead > 0)
{
    reqStream.Write(inData, 0, bytesRead);
    bytesRead = rdr.Read(inData, 0, inData.Length);
}

rdr.Close();
reqStream.Close();

req.GetResponse();
```

The uploadUrl is like this: `http://10.x.x.x./FolderName/Filename`

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: If the server is telling  you "not found", then the chances are that you're using the wrong URL. Also, your two streams and your WebResponse should be in `using` blocks.

Comment: Thank you John. Apologize about the tags in title. When I open the URL in a browser, it works fine. That's why it has me stumped.

Comment: When you open the URL in a browser, you are using a GET, not a PUT. Maybe you meant "POST"?

Comment: I'm getting the same error when I use "POST".

Comment: You need to find out from the "person" who owns the URL what the correct URL is. Also, try `http://10.x.x.x/FolderName/FileName` without the trailing `.` in the host part of the URL.

Comment: @John,That trailing . was a typo on this post. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Please use **"POST"** method instead of **"PUT"** and I guess it will work.

**Edit:**

Check the code below, it will help you.

```
 public void UploadFile()
    {
        string fileUrl = @"enter file url here";
        string parameters = @"image=" + Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(fileUrl));
        WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(new Uri("location url here"));

        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        req.Method = "POST";
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(parameters);

        try
        {
            req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
            Stream s = req.GetRequestStream();
            s.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            s.Close();
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            throw ex; //Request exception.
        }

        try
        {
            WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(req.GetResponseStream());
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            throw ex; //Response exception.
        }
    }
```

Enter fileUrl variable correctly and take care of uri while creating WebRequest instance, write the url of the locating folder.

Comment: Actually, the uploadUrl is wrong and the problem caused by that. You should pass the link of the folder not link of the image or file. Please check it.

Comment: Thank you, When I just use the Link of the folder, I now get a message saying: 405 Method not allowed.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm using asp.net 1.1, Methods like : File.ReadAllBytes don't exist.

Comment: Are you sure that, the server supports "POST" method? That error causes due to that generally.

Comment: Where do I check that?

Comment: Please "Google" it, you should understand the basics of HTTP methods such as "POST, "GET", "PUT" etc. You will understand what is the problem, why that method is not allowed but for now, we solved the problem on the title.

Comment: @Abhi: if POST doesn't work for you, then this answer should not be accepted